# On click of submit how to display the table and pass the form value to backend in html and js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form-submit, submit-button

I'm developing an HTML page that accepts the date value as input and needs to display the data in a table based on the dates.
On page load, I'm displaying the Date field and Submit button.

On click of the submit button, I need to perform 2 operations:

1)The date values should get submitted so that I can fetch those values at the backend and pass them to python API.
2)Display the table on the same page where the table contains the data of that python API.

I'm able to perform the above operations separately, but in a single submit button at the same time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      var url = "{{url_for('data_api') }}";
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var thd, tbd = ' ';
        var mydata = data['data'];
        thd += '<thead style="text-align:center"><tr>';
        thd += '<th scope="col" width="15%">CustID</th>';
        thd += '<th scope="col" width="25%">CustName</th>';
        thd += '<th scope="col" width="20%">Date</th>';
        thd += '</tr></thead>

        $.each(mydata, function(key, value) {
          //Will get the data from api and insert those data in the table
        });
      });

      $("#sbtn").click(function() {
            if ($("#my_date_picker").val().length === 0){
                alert('Invalid');
                return false;
              }
              else {
                $("form").submit();
              }
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Date Picker
  </title>

  <link href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">
    Date: <input type="text" id="my_date_picker">
    <button id="sbtn">Submit</button>

    <div id="mytable">
      <table id="datatable" style="display:none">

      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(function() {
        $("#my_date_picker").datepicker();
      });
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any way to perform both operations with a SINGLE submit button.?

Comment: Hi, you need to show data based on user input ? Also you are already loading all data when page load in your table ? Why not simply show/hide tr where date matches ?

Comment: Hi @Swati, I'm hiding the table on page load and I need to display the table by clicking the submit button.

Comment: So here `data` has all datas ?

Comment: @Swati yes, It is having all the required data. The only thing is I have to show the table with the click of the submit button. Here in the `$('#sbtn')` function, after submitting the form  I'm not able to show the table.